# zsh completion: only offer specific file extensions for completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

currently, I have this in my `.zshrc`:

```
 zstyle ':completion::complete:mpv:*' menu yes select
```

In addition to using menu for `mpv` completion, I would like to limit the completions offered to only files with specified file extensions, ie `mp4`, `mp3`, ...

how can I integrate that into my existing rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the `ignored-patterns` setting:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion::complete:mpv:*' ignored-patterns '^(*.(mp4|mp3))'
```

**However,** this will also ignore *directories* not ending in `.mp3` or `.mp4`.

If you still want directories to be completed as normal, then you have to use the slightly more complex `file-patterns` setting instead:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion::complete:mpv:*' file-patterns '
  *(D-/):local-directories:"local directory" 
  *.(mp3|mp4)(D-^/):media-files:"media file"
'
```

For an explanation of `(D-/)` and `(D-^/)`, see the [Zsh manual's section on glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

Comment: could we simplify the second rule, if I only want regular files of given type to be offered for completion? All directories can be completely ignored.

Comment: In that case, you can just use the `ignored-patterns` rule I posted.

Comment: OK, that will work. But if I wanted to make sure no directories will ever match, is there a  way to have the pattern act only on regular files?

Comment: From the `file-patterns` rule, remove the line that generates local directory completions.

Comment: sorry, but how do i integrate it with the `menu yes select`? The following does not work: `zstyle ':completion::complete:mpv:*' file-patterns '*.(mp3|mp4)(D-^/):media-files:"media file"' menu yes select`

Comment: That's not how it works. `menu` and `file-patterns` are two separate settings. You need to put each in a separate `zstyle` statement.

Comment: The syntax is `zstyle <namespace selector> <setting> <value>...`